# nginx rewrite /forum and /forums

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I need to redirect /forum and /forums to a new folder called /new.  This is to catch variations of the name/type-o, it isn't to be used as an alias directive.

I need like this:

```
/forum to /new
/forum/ to /new/
/forums to /new
/forums/ to /new/
/forum/blah to /new/blah
/forum/wee/blah.jpg to /new/wee/blah.jpg
```

I'm pulling my hair out, I know it's simple but I've tried a dozen examples and can't get it.

Using:

```
location /forum {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/new;
}
```

Only works for exactly /forum, it doesn't work for /forum/blah for example (needs to go to /new/blah).

```
02:22 AM [atlantis]/etc/nginx/sites root # curl -I xxx/forum
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 12 Sep 2015 06:22:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://xxx/new
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

02:22 AM [atlantis]/etc/nginx/sites root # curl -I xxx/forum/blah
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 12 Sep 2015 06:22:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://xxx/new
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Comment: Why HTTP 301 but not Nginx rewrite directive?

Comment: I tried both ways. Will take whatever works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
location ~ ^/forums(.*)$ {    
    return 301 /new$1;    
}

location ~ ^/forum(.*)$ {    
    return 301 /new$1;    
}
```

And "return" directive is preferable to "rewrite".

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this before I posted, only I had /forum above /forums and was getting an error.  Now that I repositioned it works!